# LLVM segmentation fault with opt command

Tags: llvm

when i am trying to run the very simple (Hello world) pass given in llvm (my file is pass Hello.cpp) on a file XX.c 
(X64 OS)
the opt command

```
opt -load ../../../Release+Asserts/lib/Hello.so -hello vv.bc > vv.txt
```

gives this error

```
0  libLLVM-3.2svn.so 0x00007f314b0f1e52
1  libLLVM-3.2svn.so 0x00007f314b0f22b3

2  libpthread.so.0   0x00007f314a0c7340

3  libstdc++.so.6    0x00007f31499645cb std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&) + 11

4  libLLVM-3.2svn.so 0x00007f314aadef1d llvm::createPrintFunctionPass(std::string const&, llvm::raw_ostream*, bool) + 77

5  libLLVM-3.2svn.so 0x00007f314aad1585 llvm::PMTopLevelManager::schedulePass(llvm::Pass*) + 37

6  opt               0x0000000000413e4f main + 4767

7  libc.so.6         0x00007f31492eeec5 __libc_start_main + 245
```

`8  opt               0x000000000040dfca`
Stack dump:

```
0.  Program arguments: opt -load ../../../Release+Asserts/lib/Hello.so -hello vv.bc
```

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

any suggestion would be appreciable. I am new to both Linux and llvm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something I found extremely useful is to use the [verifier pass](http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#verify-module-verifier).

So first, make sure basic `opt` flow works as intended, and that the input file is legal:

```
opt -verify vv.bc -o out.bc
```

Then make sure your pass results in a legal module:

```
opt -load ../../../Release+Asserts/lib/Hello.so -hello -verify vv.bc -o out.bc
```

If that still won't help, I'd fire up the debugger.

Comment: opt -verify vv.bc -o out.bc worked fine but 
opt -load ../../../Release+Asserts/lib/Hello.so -hello -verify vv.bc -o out.bc 
is giving the same error

Comment: @techcomp bummer. I'd open a debugger and try to locate the issue.